# Component Loading in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routerlink

I have a list of objects with name, email id, address and mobile number. The "name" in this list will be displaying as each line (Left side component). When I click on each name, the corresponding data (email id, address and mobile number) should be display on the right side component.

I used **routerlink** for this. But the issue is I have to specify all the data ( it will be difficult if there are more fields to be added in user data)

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/user',user.email,user.name,user.address.line1,user.address.line2,user.mobile]"
            class="list-group-item"  *ngFor="let user of userList">
            {{ user.name }}
</a>
```

and

```
{
      path: 'offer',
      component: UserComponent,children:[
        {
          path:'/:id/:name/:address1/:address2/:mobile',component:UserDetailsComponent
        }],
    },
```

Could anyone please help me either
To send the data as a complete object "user" and the path to be given in the routing   OR
To display this components in any other possible way (When I googled, mostly seen the "routerlink" option)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 Components that are not in a Child - Parent relationship you usually use a [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).
Now you have a few options, you could set a variable on the service that then holds the data. Another option would be to use a `Observable`, such as a `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject`, that you then can subscribe to with the "right" component.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I wouldn't use routing in here.
Instead, create a UserComponent and use the *ngFor on the User Components:

```
 <div *ngFor="let user of userList">
     <app-user [userData]="user"><app-user>
 </div>
```

This way you can pass the User object as to each of the User Components created. to fetch the user data in User Component you have to use @Input decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
})
export class UserComponent {
  @Input() userData: userData;
}
```

Then, you can use (click) events on the user components to do actions on the data.

( user.name and the rest of the details will be presented in each child User components. {{ user.name }} on my example would be {{userData.name}} of course)